# What is the issue with my branches? (ARM Assembly)

Tags: arm

I am working with the following code right now:

```
push {r1-r2, lr}
mov r1, r0
ldrb r2, [r1]

cmp r2, #'0'
blt notNum
cmpgt r2, #'9'
bgt notNum
ldrltb r2, [r1, #1]
cmplt r2, #0
beq isNum
bne notNum

isNum:
mov r0, #1
notNum:
mov r0, #0
```

The purpose of this particular code is to take in a string stored in r0 and test whether it is a number or not. The issue I am having at present is that for some reason the first cmp is always resulting in branching to notNum via blt. I've done some gdb testing and assuming my logic is correct (cmp = input1 - input2) then the compare flag would be greater than. Any insight into my issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is this being called - what _exactly_ is in r0? If it is a pointer, what _exactly_ is it pointing to? This code alone isn't enough for anyone to reproduce what you're describing (for all we know r2 is just something less than 48). Note also that execution is ultimately always going to pass through `notNum` anyway, regardless of the branches.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. r0 is a pointer to a string containing the number entered, pointing to the first character. I've been testing it for the input 1 and it is branching to notNum anyways from the first cmp. The end goal is to return 0 if the value in the string is not a number and 1 if it is. Good to know about notNum executing regardless though.

Comment: @Dingusamingus - there are other conditional execution options like eorlt r0, r0 & movgt r0, #1 to reduce branching.

Comment: Have you looked at the code a compiler will generate for `if (x <= '9' && x >= '0')`? You might be surprised by how many branches an optimizing compiler needs...